# Accelerating the following code using Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to use Numba to accelerate a piece of code. The code is simple, basically a loop with simple calculations on a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from numba import jit, double

def MinimizeSquareDiffBudget(x, budget):
    if (budget > np.sum(x)):
        return x
    n = np.size(x,0)
    j = 1
    i = 0
    y = np.zeros((n, 1))
    while (budget > 0):
        while (x[i] == x[j]) and (j < n-1):
            j += 1
        i = j - 1
        if (np.std(x)<1e-10):
            to_give = budget/n
            y += to_give
            x= x- to_give
            break
        to_give = min(budget, (x[0] - x[j])*j)
        y[0:j] += to_give/j
        x[0:j]=x[0:j]-to_give/j
        budget = budget - to_give
        j = 1
    return y
```

Now, I tried optimizing it using @jit and by defining:

```
fastMinimizeSquareDiffBudget = jit(double[:,:](double[:,:], double[:,:]))(MinimizeSquareDiffBudget)
```

However, the time is roughly the same, while I expected Numba to be much faster.

Testing the code:

```
budget = 335.0

x = np.random.uniform(0,1,(1000,1))
x.sort(axis=0)
x = x[::-1]
t = time.process_time()
y = MinimizeSquareDiffBudget(x, budget)
print(time.process_time()-t)

x = np.random.uniform(0,1,(1000,1))
x.sort(axis=0)
x = x[::-1]

t = time.process_time()
y = fastMinimizeSquareDiffBudget(x, budget)
print(time.process_time()-t)
```

takes 0.28 secs for the direct implementation and 0.45 secs for the optimized code with Numba. The same code written in C takes less than 0.001 secs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you time only one execution of the jitted function, you are seeing both the run time and the time it takes Numba to jit the code. If you run the code a second time you'll see the actual speed-up since Numba uses an in-memory cache of the compiled function so you only pay the compilation time once per argument type.

On my machine using python 3.6 and numba 0.31.0, the pure python function takes 0.32 seconds. The first time I call `fastMinimizeSquareDiffBudget` it takes 0.57 seconds, but the second time it takes 0.31 seconds.

Now the reason you're not seeing a huge speed-up is because you have a function that Numba can't compile in `nopython` mode, so it falls back to the much slower `object mode`. If you pass `nopython=True` to the `jit` method, you'll be able to see where it can't compile. The two issues I saw were that you should use `x.shape[0]` instead of `np.size(x,0)`, and you can't use `min` in the way you are.